# how to display a menu BEFORE a prompt message Thanks yall

Tags: javascript, menu, prompt

I'm a beginner
I can't show a choice menu before my prompt message (make your choice)
The prompt message show first and i can't see my menu at the same time it only appear after i type a choice
Thanks

Comment: Your question needs to show the code you are working with.

Comment: function choixUseur() {
  console.log("1 : List contacts");
  console.log("2 : Add contact");
  console.log("0 : Quit");
  console.log("");
 
  choix = Number(prompt("Make your choice :"));
  return choix;

Comment: I mean actually edit your question.  Adding it in an unformatted comment isn't very helpful either.

Comment: Why are you doing this with `console.log` and `prompt`? Most users don't have the browser console open, it's just for debugging. Use form fields in the DOM.

Comment: I use console.log and prompt because i'm learning and it's just what i know

Comment: and this is to make an exercice . I'm not make lesson about DOM yet

Answer (score 0):

Using `prompt()` you block the browsers execution including the rendering & logging, which means that the menu wouldn't render even though you added it:

```
console.log("You cant see me :)";
prompt("But you can see this");
```

The only solution to this is to defer the call to prompt, so that it happens after a rerender:

```
console.log("Now you see me");
setTimeout(function () {
  prompt("me too");
}, 10);
```

Now while that works, `prompt()` doesn't look that nice and your users probably do not know where the console is, so you should rather use some `<input />` on the page.

Comment: Great thank you; It works; i just set the time at 10 instead 0 to see the message AND the prompt. Thanks again